# Security Error when trying to communicate with Twitter from Flex

Tags: apache-flex, security

When I try to request a token from Twitter:

```
                _consumer = new OAuthConsumer( _consumerKey, _consumerSecret );
                var oauthRequest:OAuthRequest = new OAuthRequest( "GET", AppConstants.TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, null, _consumer, null );
                var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest( oauthRequest.buildRequest( _signature ) );
                var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(   );
                loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;  
                loader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, requestTokenHandler );
                loader.load(request);
```

I get the following Security Error:

```
Security ERROR: [SecurityErrorEvent type="securityError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: http://localhost:3000/bin/testsite.swf cannot load data from http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_consumer_key=....."]
```

Althought I have added the following:

```
            Security.allowDomain("*");
            Security.loadPolicyFile("http://twitter.com/crossdomain.xml");
```

The weird thing is that it doesn't happen when I run my App in Debug mode (from Flash Builder) it just happens when I call my application from localhot:3000 (as I'm using Rails)!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. The problem here, like with many other web services, is that the `crossdomain.xml` is not permissive enough. This is true with Twitter's crossdomain.xml and of any domain that doesn't have a crossdomain.xml file.

Here's [Twitter's crossdomain.xml](http://twitter.com/crossdomain.xml).

> <cross-domain-policy xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.adobe.com/xml/schemas/PolicyFile.xsd">
>
> <allow-access-from domain="twitter.com"/>
>   <allow-access-from domain="api.twitter.com"/>
>   <allow-access-from domain="search.twitter.com"/>
>   <allow-access-from domain="static.twitter.com"/>
>
> <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
>
> <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*.twitter.com" headers="*" secure="true"/>
>
> </cross-domain-policy>

For you to have access to ANYTHING at twitter.com you would have to load your swf from one of the domains listed in `allow-access-from`. Since you probably aren't loading your swf from api.twitter.com you need to proxy your calls to Twitter's API from a server behind a domain you control. Essentially, you will write most of your code in a server-side language like PHP and make calls to that from your swf.

The reason everything works when debugging is because there's no sandbox security when loading a swf directly from your local filesystem (not from a local or remote server).

Check out the [whitepaper on Flash security](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/flash_player10_security_wp.html) and [crossdomain spec](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html) for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that Twitter's crossdomain policy allows any domain to make requests to it.  In which case you will need to use a server proxy like mod_proxy or BlazeDS.